# how to get all the predicted label names in multi-label text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I m working on a multi-label text classification, there are total 34 labels. I have completed the training of my model. In predictions i want to get the names of all the labels which are predicted by my model, but i am stuck to get them.
i have tried the `np.argmax(model.predict(pred), axis=-1)` but it is giving me only one label as an output.

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('/cnn.h5')

CATEGORIES=['070.32', '070.33', '070.54', '155.0', '197.7', '271.0', '271.8',
       '275.1', '277.4', '289.81', '401.9', '452', '453.0', '511.89',
       '553.1', '567.23', '571.2', '571.42', '571.5', '571.6', '571.8',
       '572.2', '572.3', '572.4', '576.1', '578.9', '728.3', '751.61',
       '780.97', '782.3', '782.4', '786.3', '789.5', 'V70.8']

encoded_label = np.argmax(model.predict(x_test), axis=-1)[0] 
Labels = CATEGORIES[encoded_label]
Labels
```

The output i am getting is one different code every time because of argmax function, like:

```
[V70.8]
```

the Output i want is all names of predicted labels (may be two labels, three labels, four labels and so on)

```
[V70.8, 155.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the required output for the first 10 test data:

Please mention `len(x_test)` in place of 10 to get the entire test data predictions.

```
#(`for i in range(len(x_test)):`)

for i in range(10):  #
  encoded_label = np.argmax(probability_model.predict(x_test), axis=-1)[i]
  Labels = CATEGORIES[encoded_label]
  print("x_test",format(i),"has probability = ",np.argmax(probability_model.predict(x_test)[i]),"and predicted as Label = ",Labels)
```

Comment: @TEer2 thank you for your kind reply. I tried this code but again it returns one label per sample. however model is expected to return multiple labels.